# Rare memory consumption

Tags: ssh, memory, display, centos-7

I`m suffering a strange behaviour that drives me crazy. I'm trying to run some compass listeners on my server startup, i've tried in several ways, all of them with the root user.

1. Creating a service to run "my script"
2. Running "my script" from /etc/rc.local
3. Running command directly from /etc/rc.local
4. Running "my script" from cron @restart
5. Running "my script" manually from ssh session with root user
6. Running manually the commands of "my script" from ssh with root user

All of them worked as expected, everything but memory consumption.

In the last 2 cases, running script/commands from ssh, the 2 detached screens cerated consumes what i think is a normal memory consumption:

[image: Processes A]

But in the other 4 ways, the detached screens consumes a very high amount of resources:

[image: Processes B]

The command is so simple (runned 2 times for different folders):

```
screen -dm -S name_a compass watch /target_folder
```

Please, can anyone please give me some clue of what can be happening?

Comment: Memory consumption seems to be the same in all cases.

Comment: Sorry i meant %CPU (thank you for pointing the obvious).
I finally fixed it by replacing the symbolic links that were on the target_folder path.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about `compass`, but a few things off the bat.

Memory usage seems similar at 0.6% in both cases, it's CPU usage that's different.

What's different between the first 4 and the last 2 interactive ("manual") sessions you started:

- environment variables (`export`) will be different, shell (`bash`/`sh`)
  might be different too;
- `stdin`/`stdout`/`stderr` will be connected to your terminal in the interactive logins, and connected to `/dev/null` in the first 4 cases. Is the `compass` command expecting input or output, and handling the lack thereof inefficiently?

Again, I don't know `compass` – just some thoughts.

Comment: Thank you very much, finally i've fixed it as i noticed in the above comment.

Comment: Sorry i've forgot, just for pure information. compass (with sass) is a stylesheet preprocessor, the command "watch" will watch all .scss or .sass files inside a folder, and whenever it detects any change over any of those files it will automatically compile it's corresponding .css file. Regards!.